# Passing on a char* which contains a path

Tags: c++, windows, string, path

I'm trying to pass through several functions a string with a path but the every '\\' I put in the path becomes a single '\' in the inner function and I can't use it this way.
Is there a way to preserve the "\\" when entering a new function?
I'm using C++ on windows.
thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Be prepared for some obfuscated answer.

The `\` is the escape character (you have probably already encountered the `\n` escape sequence for example), and `\\` is the escape sequence that represents a single `\` character (in a sense, it can be understood as an escape of the escape character). If you really want to have `\\` in your string, you'll have to use `\\\\` :

```
std::cout << "\\\\something\\" << std::endl; /* prints "\\something\" */
```

Just to provide another example, suppose you'd like to have some `"` in a string. Writing :

```
const char *str = "Hello "World"";
```

will obviously not compile, and you will have to escape the `"` with a `\` :

```
const char *str = "Hello \"World\"";
```

Comment: +1, Although, "will obviously not compile" unless someone #defines World and then it's not so obvious anymore.

Comment: I know, but I hoped that I wouldn't have to  write strings with monsters like "\\\\\\"... is there no other way?

Answer (score 2):

In C++0x you will have a raw string literal:

```
R"(anything can appear here, even " or \\ )"
```

Where everything between "( and )" is part of the string -- no escaping necessary. In the current standard you can't achieve what you want.